# Is Field Unique?

Tags: vector-spaces

I am learning Dual Space and it is defined as a set of linear transformation from given Vector space to "Field".

What I know about field is, it is a set which retains algebraic structure multiplication and summation with its inverse identity and identity.

Then my question is, is field always unique?

I mean.. is there any different types or classifications of Field

Comment: The field is just the number system that the vector space is defined on. So if the vectors in the vector space has components that are real numbers, the field is the real numbers. Vector spaces can be over other number systems (i.e. fields) like the complex numbers too and other more abstract number systems. If your field is the real numbers, the dual of the vector space is the set of all linear maps from the vector space to the real numbers.

Comment: Unique to what ... ? to a given vector space ?

Comment: @Mudream: Yes, the field is already "unique" to the given vector space.  The vector space definition tells us which field contains the *scalars* of the vector space properties/operations.

Answer (score 2):

The field underlying a vector space is part of the basic data associated with a vector space. That is, when we say $V$ is a vector space it is understood that there is a field $F$ such that $V$ is a vector space over $F$.

However, a vector space can very well be a vector space over a different field. Specifically, if $V$ is a vector space over $F$ and $E$ is a subfield of $F$ then $V$ is also a vector space over $E$.

One particular example is that every vector space over the complex numbers is also a vector space over the real numbers and over the rational numbers. Moreover, if $V$ is a finite dimensional complex vector space then $\dim_\mathbf{R} V = 2 \dim_\mathbf{C} V$.